# Is there a way to find Active Directory on the network without providing any info in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

I'm looking for a way to find Active Directory on the network (probably thru DNS/DHCP settings assigned) and then trying to access it, getting all the things like AD servername, BaseDN or domain name from within a code without asking user to provide information about his network. Is there a way to go?

```
    private  string strADServerName = "SERVERAD";
    private  string strBaseDN = "DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM";
    private  string strAccountFilter = "sAMAccountName";
    private  string domainName = "DOMAIN";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install a Active-Directory you need a Dynamic DNS (DDNS). During his installation AD registers information in the DNS, as you can see in the following capture. On a given Windows computer the WMI class `win32_ComputerSystem` can provide you the domain name.

[image]

You can see here under the detail of `_ldap` entry :

[image]

This `SRV` entry provide DNS address and port of the domain controllers of your domain. `_ldap` entry can have multiple values as you've got multiple domain controllers in your domain.

Using `NSLOOKUP.EXE` tool, you can get this information as shown here under :

```
> set type=SRV
> _ldap._tcp.dom.fr
Serveur :   UnKnown
Address:  192.168.183.100

_ldap._tcp.dom.fr       SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = wm2008r2ent.dom.fr
wm2008r2ent.dom.fr      internet address = 192.168.183.100
```

If you don't know the domain you can just query for `_ldap._tcp` like in the sample above :

```
> _ldap._tcp
Serveur :   UnKnown
Address:  192.168.183.100

_ldap._tcp.dom.fr       SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = wm2008r2ent.dom.fr
wm2008r2ent.dom.fr      internet address = 192.168.183.100
```

On the C# point of view, I am not sure that the class `System.Net.DNS` allow you to query SRV records. You can find in [this codeplex entry](http://dndns.codeplex.com/) DnDNS assembly seems to do it.

Comment: I know about nslookup method .. although you still have to type _ldap._tcp.dom.fr don't you? so you have to know what you're looking for ?

Comment: win32_ComputerSystem can give you the "dom.fr" part.

Comment: Will it supply that on non-domain computer as well ?

Comment: Of course not. What do you really want to do ? discover AD on a network from nothing ?

Comment: Well yes. I have computer which isn't in domain but I need it to be able to discover Active Directory when it's attached to the network. So that in program I will write I won't have to type in the domain name and so on but I could just pick it from choice menu and program would do the rest. Considering that DHCP assings me DNS which is also Active Directory this should be doable.

Comment: with '_ldap._tcp' if the 'DNS suffix for this conexion' is correctly parametered in the IP stack it should be doable.