# How to get the IADs interface of an active directory user?

Tags: winapi, active-directory

How can i get the [`IADs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface of an Active Directory user - by *username*?

**Note**: Native code

---

i am trying to write the function that can get the [`IADs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface of a *user* in Active Directory.

i have the following "pseudocode" so far:

```
public IADs GetUserObject(string samAccountName)
{
   IADs ads;

   //Get the current domain's distinguished name ("dc=stackoverflow,dc=com")
   AdsGetObject("LDAP://rootDSE", IADs, ref ads);
   String dn = ads.Get("defaultNamingContext"); //"dc=stackoverflow,dc=com"

   String path;

   //Attempt #1 to bind to a user by username
   path = "LDAP://sSAMAccountName="+samAccountName+",dc=stackoverflow,dc=com"
   AdsGetObject(path, IADs, ref ads); //invalid syntax

   return ads;       
}
```

The trick, that i cannot figure out, is how to bind to the user by their account name. The following variantions don't work:

- `LDAP://sSAMAccountName=ian,dc=stackoverflow,dc=com`
- `LDAP://dc=stackoverflow,dc=com;(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=ian))`
- `<LDAP://dc=stackoverflow,dc=com>;(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=ian))`

> **Edit**:
>
> A version that *does* work, but doesn't answer my question, is:
>
> - `LDAP://cn=Ian Boyd,ou=Avatar Users,dc=stackoverflow,dc=com`
>
> It doesn't answer my question for two reasons:
>
> - i don't know the user's `CN` (Common-Name) (e.g. Ian Boyd), only their `sAMAccountName` (e.g. ian)
> - doesn't work for users not in the **Avatar Users** organizational unit; and i don't know a user's OU
>
> Which comes from the notes i had before:

**Note:**

- i don't know the name of the domain (but that's okay, i can get it at runtime)
- i don't know the name of any active directory servers
- i don't know the folder that the user is in

---

tl;dr: How would you write the utility function:

```
public IADs GetUserObject(string samAccountName)
{
   //TODO: ask stackoverflow
}
```

**Update 2:**

**Note**:

- i already know how to query for information about a user [using .NET's DirectorySearcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8564675/12597)
- i already know how to query for information about a user [using the Active Directory Services OLEDB provider with ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575614/12597) (using the SQL syntax, but not the native syntax)
- i'm now looking for code to query for information about a user [using Active Directory Services COM objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567800/12597) (hence the question about getting an `IADs` for a user)

**Update 3**:

It certainly might require me to apply "*filters*", except i don't know where. The only ActiveDs interface that mentions **Filter** is [`IADSContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but i don't know where to get one.

i tried randomly to get the `IADsContainer` interface from the root `IADs` interface, but "rootDSE" doesn't support `IADsContainer`:

```
IADs ads = AdsGetObject("LDAP://rootDSE");
IADsContainer container = (IADsContainer)ads; //interface not supported exception
```

i could

- ask a question on how to get the `IADsContainer` of the AD root

  - so i can ask how to recursively search active diretory

    - so i can ask how to filter using `IADsContainer`

      - [so i can figure out how to get the IADs object of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591789/how-to-get-the-iads-interface-of-an-active-directory-user)

        - [so i an figure out how to query AD for user properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564675/how-to-query-activedirectory-from-native-code/8567800#8567800)

But keeping track of all these questions is difficult.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol Microsoft API (as discribed in RFC 1823 )

Comment: @JPBlanc That would require *another* stackoverflow question, *"How do i get an `IADs` interface using the Lightweight Directly Access Protocol of RFC1823?"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the value of `sAMAccountName` and need to get `IADs` of the user you need first *find* the user in Active Directory by the `sAMAccountName` and get `distinguishedName` attribute of the user. You know already how to get `IADs` by `distinguishedName`.

So you should just follow [the code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#c___example) from MSDN for example. First you get `IDirectorySearch` interface of the AD container of `defaultNamingContext` of `"LDAP://rootDSE"`.

```
IADs domain;
ADsGetObject("LDAP://rootDSE", IADs, domain);
```

Then you use [IDirectorySearch::ExecuteSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to apply search using the filter string:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=theName))
```

**Note:** The search filter syntax is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
IDirectorySearch directorySearch = domain as IDirectorySearch;
ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE searchHandle;

directorySearch.ExecuteSearch(
      "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=ian))",
      attributeNames, numberOfAttributes,
      out searchHandle);
```

- you use the known value of `sAMAccountName` instead of `theName`.
- for `pAttributeNames` you can use `LPOLESTR` array which consist from `L"distinguishedName"` only (see `pszNonVerboseList` from the code example and look the code of `FindUsers` in case of `bIsVerbose` as `FALSE`).

You should get `distinguishedName` attribute of first (and the only if any exist) found item. Having `distinguishedName` attribute you can use `AdsGetObject` to get the `IADs` of the user.

Alternatively you can get `objectGUID` attribute of the user instead of `distinguishedName` attribute and use [binding by GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) syntax, but the usage of `distinguishedName` I personally find more clear and understandable.

---

```
public IADs GetUserObject(string samAccountName)
{
   IADs ads;

   //Get the current domain's distinguished name (e.g. "dc=stackoverflow,dc=com")
   AdsGetObject("LDAP://rootDSE", IADs, ref ads);
   String dn = ads.Get("defaultNamingContext"); //"dc=stackoverflow,dc=com"

   //Get the the object of the current domain (e.g. LDAP://dc=stackoverflow,dc=com)
   AdsGetObject("LDAP://"+dn, IADs, ref ads);

   //Now we're going to search for the "distinguishedName" of this user

   //setup the search filter for the user we want
   String filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName="+samAccountName+"))";

   //specify that we only need to return one attribute, distinguishedNamem, 
   //otherwise it returns all attributes and is a waste of resources
   String[] searchAttributes = { "distinguishedName" };

   //run the search
   IDirectorySearch ds = ads as IDirectorySearch;
   ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE searchHandle;
   ds.ExecuteSearch(filter, searchAttributes, 1, out searchHandle);
   ds.GetFirstRow(searchHandle);

   //Now get the details of the "distinguishedName" column
   ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN column;
   ds.GetColumn(searchHandle, "distinguishedName", ref column);

   //Get the user's distinguishedName
   String dn = column.pADsValues.DNString;


   //Now that we have the user's distinguishedName, we can do what we really wanted:
   AdsGetObject("LDAP://"+dn, IADs, ads);

   return ads;
}
```

This means that conceptually it can be broken down into two steps:

- getting a user's **distinguishedName** from their `samAccountName`
- fetching the `IADs` for a **distinguishedName**

And splitting the code:

```
public IADs GetUserObject(string samAccountName)
{
   String userDistinguishedName = GetUserDistinguishedName(samAccountName);

   return GetObject("LDAP://"+userDistingishedName);
}

public String GetUserDistinguishedName(string samAccountName)
{
   //Get the current domain's distinguished name (e.g. "dc=stackoverflow,dc=com")
   IADs ads = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE");
   String dn = ads.Get("defaultNamingContext"); //"dc=stackoverflow,dc=com"

   //Get the the object of the current domain (e.g. LDAP://dc=stackoverflow,dc=com)
   ads := GetObject("LDAP://"+dn);

   //Now we're going to search for the "distinguishedName" of this user

   //setup the search filter for the user we want
   String filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName='+samAccountName+'))';

   //specify that we only need to return one attribute, distinguishedNamem, 
   //otherwise it returns all attributes and is a waste of resources
   String[] searchAttributes = { "distinguishedName" };

   //run the search
   IDirectorySearch ds = ads as IDirectorySearch;
   ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE searchHandle;
   ds.ExecuteSearch(filter, searchAttributes, 1, out searchHandle);
   ds.GetFirstRow(searchHandle);

   //Now get the details of the "distinguishedName" column
   ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN column;
   ds.GetColumn(searchHandle, "distinguishedName", ref column);

   //Get the user's distinguishedName
   return column.pADsValues.DNString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample in C++

```
IADs *pObject;
HRESULT hr;

// Initialize COM.
CoInitialize(NULL);

hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://CN=JPB,OU=MonOU,DC=societe,DC=fr", 
        IID_IADs,
        (void**) &pObject);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Use the object.

    // Release the object.
    pObject->Release()
}

// Uninitialize COM.
CoUninitialize();
```

You can find more information in [Binding to Active Directory Domain Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772152%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: When i call `AdsGetObject` with `LDAP://cn=ian,dc=avatopia,dc=com` i get hresult `$80072030` ("There is no such object on the server"). Presumably because `ian` is not the **Common-Name** (`CN`), but the `sAMAccountName`. (i.e. i only know the account name).